# Calling a python Command-line tool with arguments, with PythonKit using Swift

Tags: python, swift, swift-pythonkit

I have been experimenting a bit with PythonKit and have some simple examples working. However I would now like to call a python script that takes some command line arguments and I can’t seem to get it working - it mostly just crashes.

This is the code I am using in swift - I am trying to get the version number of the script:

```
let sys = Python.import("sys")
sys.path.append(“/Path/To/Script/Directory/“)
var example = Python.import(“my_script”)

example.main("-v")
```

If I call the script like so: example.main() - without any arguments at all, the script prints out its arguments:

```
optional arguments:
    -v, --version         show program's version number and exit
    -H, --help            Display this information
    etc.
```

But PythonKit then crashes in:

```
@discardableResult
    func dynamicallyCall(
        withArguments args: [PythonConvertible] = []) -> PythonObject {
        return try! throwing.dynamicallyCall(withArguments: args)
    }
```

The crash seems to be caused by a call to sys.exit(0) in the python script just after the argument list is printed, when there are no arguments. The script works normally if I use it in the terminal.

So, can someone tell me how to call a python script that expects arguments, from PythonKit?

Also, is there something that I could do to prevent a crash if there are no arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with swift but know that `python` getting arguments from `sys.argv` list

So how about try to add arguments directly into `sys` object:

```swift
let sys = Python.import("sys")
sys.path.append(“/Path/To/Script/Directory/“)
sys.argv.append("-v")
var example = Python.import(“my_script”)
example.main()
```